# List of different Nodes is producing a list only one node

Tags: python, list, nodes

I need help. My code isnt producing a list of different Nodes, rather they are all the same and I dont know why.

```
def init(logger, playerId, numWalls, playerHomes):

"""
    Part 1 - 4

    The engine calls this function once at the beginning of the game.
    The student player module uses this function to initialize its data
    structures to the initial game state.

    Parameters
        logger: a reference to the logger object. The player model uses
            logger.write(msg) and logger.error(msg) to log diagnostic
            information.

        playerId: this player's number, from 1 to 4

        numWalls: the number of walls each player is given initially

        playerHomes: An ordered tuple of player locations
                     A location is a 2-element tuple of (row,column).
                     If any player has already been eliminated from
                     the game (rare), there will be a bool False in
                     that player's spot in the tuple instead of a
                     location.

    returns:
        a PlayerData object containing all of this player module's data
"""

class Node:
#online lecture notes for class

    """
     Node represents a node in a graph using adjacency lists.
     Node.name is a String.
     Node.neighbors is a ListOfNode.
    """


    __slots__ = ( 'name', 'neighbors' )

    def __init__(self, name):
        """
        __init__: Node * String -> None
        Constructs a node object with the given name and no neighbors.
        """
        self.name = name
        self.neighbors = []

NodeList = []
row = 0
col = 0
while row < 9:
    while col < 9:
        Node.name = (row,col)
        Node.neighbors = neigh(Node.name)
        print(str(Node))
        NodeList.append(Node)
        col = col + 1
        print(str(Node.name))
        print(str(Node.neighbors))
    col = 0
    row = row + 1
count = 0

print(NodeList[0])
print(Node.neighbors)


def neigh(node):
    name=node
    if name == (0, 0): #top left corner
        neighbors = [ None, ( 0+1, 0 ), ( 0, 0+1), None]
    elif name == (0, 8): #top right corner
        neighbors = [ None, ( 0+1, 8 ), None, (0, 8-1)]
    elif name == (8, 0): #bot left corner
        neighbors = [ (8-1, 0) , None, (8, 0+1), None]
    elif name == (8, 8): #bot right corner
        neighbors = [ (8-1, 8), None, None, (8,8-1)]
    elif name[0] < 1:
        neighbors = [ None, (name[0]+1, name[1] ), (name[0], name[1]+1 ), (name[0], name[1]-1)]
    elif name[0] > 7:
        neighbors = [ (name[0]-1, name[1] ), None, (name[0], name[1]+1 ), (name[0]-1, name[1]-1)]
    elif name[1] < 1:
        neighbors = [ (name[0]-1, name[1] ), (name[0]+1, name[1] ), (name[0], name[1]+1 ), None]
    elif name[1] > 7:
        neighbors = [ (name[0]-1, name[1] ), (name[0]+1, name[1] ), None, (name[0], name[1]-1)]
    else:
        neighbors = [ (name[0]-1, name[1] ), (name[0]+1, name[1] ), (name[0], name[1]+1 ), (name[0], name[1]-1)]

    return neighbors

init(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Could you explain what is not working exactly?

Comment: This code produces a NodeList that is only the Node.name (8,8) and I need the list to have all of the number up to (8,8)

Comment: This part is not adding all of the correct nodes to the list. I am not sure why.        
        while col < 9:
        Node.name = (row,col)
        Node.neighbors = neigh(Node.name)
        print(str(Node))
        NodeList.append(Node)

Comment: What did you use while statements for `row` and `col`? I would recommend using `for` statements with `range()` function. Example: `for row in range(10):` which would iterate the variable `row` from 0 to 9 inclusively without having to manually reset the initial value every time, and increment the value every loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
    Node.name = (row,col)
    Node.neighbors = neigh(Node.name)
```

you need to create an instance of `Node`:

```
    node = Node()
    node.name = (row,col)
    node.neighbors = neigh(node.name)
```

and use `node` instead of `Node` throughout.

Comment: Adding an instance of Node() didn't seem to fix the problem... then again i wasn't sure whether or not I should throw something in the brackets of Node()